# UIActionSheet... How to implement UIImagePicker?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uiimagepickercontroller, uiactionsheet

I'm new to iOS developement... I want to add 3 buttons on this view: cancel, choose from library and take from camera.
I already know the UIImagePicker method.
Thanks

Comment: Have you considered searching on the web? or even SO

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ciao Davide, reading `UIImagePickerController` Class Reference should be useful:

> You can customize an image picker controller to manage user interactions yourself. To do this, provide an overlay view containing
>   the controls you want to display, and use the methods described in
>   “Capturing Still Images or Movies.” You can display your custom
>   overlay view in addition to, or instead of, the default controls.
>   Custom overlay views for the `UIImagePickerController` class are
>   available in iOS 3.1 and later by way of the cameraOverlayView
>   property. For a code example, see the PhotoPicker sample code
>   project.

**Here there is UIImagePickerController Class Reference:**
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html

**And here there is PhotoPicker sample code:**
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/PhotoPicker/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010196